# How do you remove a row with a id

Tags: jquery

How do I delete the row with the ID on jQuery?
Can anyone help further.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="Anthony" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<title>No titel 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var plant_row = 0;$('#add').click(function() {
    html  = '<tr id="plant' + plant_row + '">';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="aquarium_planten[' + plant_row + '][plant_naam]" /></td>';
        html += '<td>';
        html += '<a href="#" id="remove_' + plant_row + '" >Verwijderen</a>';
        html += '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#planten table > tbody').append(html);

    plant_row++;        

    return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div id="planten">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Naam plant</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <td><button id="add" >Add</button>
        </td>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
     </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table></div></body></html>
```

I'm unfortunately not matter how I do it.
Sorry for my bad english
So I want to delete the row with the ID of the table

Comment: where is your loop? lol! plant_row =0; plant_row++ until the end of days?

Comment: and where is your `remove` call ? It is not going to remove itself just by thinking very hard about it...

Comment: If the row is made ​​between the.
<tbody>
</tbody>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest being a little more jQuery'ish and create actual elements that you can reference and add event handlers to directly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var plant_row = $(this).data('plant_row') || 0,
            tr        = $('<tr />', {id: 'plant' + plant_row}),
            td1       = $('<td />'),
            td2       = $('<td />'),
            input     = $('<input />', {
                type: 'text', 
                name: 'aquarium_planten[' + plant_row + '][plant_naam]'
            }),
            anchor    = $('<a />', {
                href: '#',
                id  : 'remove_' + plant_row,
                text: 'Verwijderen',
                on  : {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    }
                }
            });

        $('#planten table > tbody').append(
            tr.append(
                td1.append(input), 
                td2.append(anchor)
            )
        );

        $(this).data('plant_row', ++plant_row);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4rez/)

Comment: Are you sure delegating the `click` handler on the table itself would not be more "jQueryish" than registering a distinct handler for each row?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation as the rows are added dynamically:

```
$('#planten').on('click', 'a[id^="remove"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMBk6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#planten").on("click","a[id^='remove_']",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `'remove_" + plant_row + "'` so `plant_row` holds the ID you want.

Instead, do something like this:

```
html += '<a href="#" data-id="' + plant_row + ' class='remove'">Verwijderen</a>';
```

Then on click, you can do this:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $('#plant'+id).remove();
});
```